# Updated Java and Eclipse Neon.2 is not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse

I updated my jre to jre1.8.0_121, and when opening my eclipse Neon.2, my Dynamic Web Projects are filled with errors. The Java classes have errors on every line, and the .xhtml files are no longer opening with normal text editing.

Under Windows>Preference>Java>Installed JREs I updated it to read the right location. Both my java and Eclipse are 64 bit.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: check if it is compiling 1.5 or higher byte code

Comment: What host platform are you working on (linux / maxOS / windows / other)?

Comment: Check Project build path if it is using JDK 8 libraries.

Comment: I am working on Windows10 64 bit

Comment: It is compiling at a 1.6

Comment: Try something higher like 1.8